# Need help writing ping results to separate files for up and down machines

Tags: powershell

I need to ping a list of machines and have the results split between up and down into two different .txt files.

```
$PingPCs = Get-Content "C:\Temp\Cache Cleanup Project\Computerlist.txt
foreach ($PC in $PingPCs) {
        $up = Test-Connection $PC -Count 1 -Quiet
        if($up) {
                  $Response = Test-Connection $PC -Count 1 | Select-Object Name
                  $Response ## Need help figuring out the outfile process to write to .txt ##
        }
        else {
              $Failed = "$PC is not reachable"
              $Failed ### Need help figuring out the outfile process to write to .txt ###
        }
}
```

The two places I need help with is just writing the results to separate text files.  One file named Online.txt and the other Offline.txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, instead of exporting the results on each iteration and appending to a file, it's a better idea to first perform your test and save the results in memory. Once all is complete, export the results:

```
$PingPCs = Get-Content "C:\Temp\Cache Cleanup Project\Computerlist.txt"

$result = foreach ($PC in $PingPCs)
{
    $testConnection = Test-Connection $PC -Count 1 -Quiet

    [pscustomobject]@{
        ComputerName = $PC
        TestConnection = $testConnection
    }
}

$result.where({$_.TestConnection}) | Out-File "x:\path\to\online.txt"
$result.where({-not $_.TestConnection}) | Out-File "x:\path\to\offline.txt"
```

#### Edit

Adding nice optimization to export the results. Thanks [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67928584/need-help-writing-ping-results-to-separate-files-for-up-and-down-machines/67928656?noredirect=1#comment120065892_67928656)

```
$online, $offline = $result.where({$_.TestConnection},'Split')
$online | Out-File "x:\path\to\online.txt"
$offline | Out-File "x:\path\to\offline.txt"
```

Comment: @MjrPayne be aware, `Test-Connection` is not always the best `cmdlet` to test if computers are online or offline. If the host has ICMP blocked you would think the host is offline when it is not. You might want to have a look at [`Test-NetConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=windowsserver2019-ps) :)